# Mysql search of 118 million rows taking 86 seconds

Tags: mysql, indexing

I was given a Mysql Innodb with 2 tables. One is 117+ million rows and has over 340 columns, including name, address, city, state and zip. The second table is 17+ million rows that has name, address, city, state and zip plus email. The data in the 1st and 2nd tables will not be added to or updated. There is a primary key on an id in each table. There are no other indexes defined.

I first created a contacts table from the 117+ million row table which has just the name, address, city, state, and zip  making it significantly smaller. I wrote a php script to perform a search using each row from the smaller table of 17+ million records, trying to find a match in the contacts table. When one is found, I insert the id and email into a separate table. I cancelled it because it was taking approximately 86 seconds per search. With 17+ million records it will take forever to finish.

Here is my search query:

```
q= "SELECT id FROM GB_contacts 
WHERE LAST_NAME=\"$LAST\" and FIRST_NAME=\"$FIRST\" and MI=\"$MIDDLE\" 
and ADDRESS=\"$ADDRESS\" and ZIP=\"$ZIP\"".
```

My question is how can I do this faster? Should I make an index on name, address, and zip in the contacts table or should I index each column in the contacts table? Is there a faster way of doing this through mysql? I have read a whole bunch of different resources and am unsure which is the best way to go. Since these are such large tables, anything I try to do takes a very long time, so I am hoping to get some expert advice and avoid wasting days, weeks and months trying to figure this out. Thank-you for any helpful advice!

Comment: You plan on doing 17 million separate queries? Even with indexes this is going to take forever. Better bet is to use a set-based solution using joins. Should be able to use just one insert statement but you need to show us more info about the tables...

Comment: @DJ.: I believe that he is running the query on 17 million rows, not 17 million times. That would be extremely inefficient and probably cause a system hold-up/ crash.

Comment: "perform a search using each row from the smaller table of 17+ million records" - sounds like 17 million times to me

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments! DJ -  You are correct as far as the search. Crazy, I know, hence my question. Thanks for the suggestion and I'm looking into a join. From what I recall, a join creates a temporary table and I need a permanent table. Is that right and can I create a permanent table from a join? As far as the info about the table: id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(30), LAST_NAME VARCHAR(30),  MIDDLE VARCHAR(1), ADDRESS VARCHAR(47) ZIP MEDIUMINT(5) UNSIGNED.

Comment: This is also taking a very, very long time. I have to SSH to my server and I keep getting a broken pipe.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create a clustered index on the fields that you are matching on. In this case, it might be a good idea to start with the zip code, followed by either first or last name first--last names are longer, so take longer to match, but are also more distinct, so it will leave less rows to do further matching (you will have to test which performs better). The strategy here is to tell mysql to look just in pockets of people, rather than search the entire database. While doing this, you got to be clever where to tell MySQL to begin narrowing it down. While you test, don't forget to use the EXPLAIN command.

Comment: This sounds promising, but can you give me an example of creating a clustered index? From what I have read there it seems that I can't create one on a table that has a primary key. Here is my table: id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(30), LAST_NAME VARCHAR(30), MIDDLE VARCHAR(1), ADDRESS VARCHAR(47) ZIP MEDIUMINT(5) UNSIGNED.

Comment: I think I would create the index like this: `CREATE INDEX idx1 ON tbl1 (ZIP,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)`. That way, the query will first look up the rows with the proper zip code, then the rows within that with the proper first name, and then the proper last name. I imagine that in no case that should leave the server with so many rows that it will need to construct a temporary table for additional sorting. Do mind that this index, on a database that large, will take it's toll on insertion and updates. On the note of having a primary key: it shouldn't be an issue. I assume that you are using InnoDB.

Comment: ...(cont)...In this case the indexes are leaved in the table itself. Because of this, you might want to consider adding an A_I field to the index (at the end) so you can make the index unique and can remove the PK. This will guarantee that the data in the table will be sorted according to the index I just described. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried typical join, if your join key is indexed it shouldn't take much time.

if its one time you can create indexes on join columns.

second step would be to load the records returned into new contacts table.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of your feedback. I got it working very efficiently by breaking everything up into multiple tables, creating indexes and then merging the tables. Now my searches take seconds. :-)